# Activar por padrão o corrector ortográfico no título da pergunta

Tags: bug, novo-recurso, status-futuro

Ao contrário do que acontece na caixa de texto do corpo, o corrector ortográfico não vem activo na caixa de texto do título da pergunta.
O mesmo acontece na caixa de "Resumo da Edição".

É possível alterar esse comportamento?

A activação por padrão do corrector ortográfico ajudaria a diminuir alguns dos erros ortográficos que muitos títulos apresentam.

Uso o Firefox.

---

## English Version

**Title:** Enable the spell checker by default in the question title

Unlike what happens in the question body text box, the spell checker is not enabled in the question title box.
The same thing happens for the "Edit summary" box.

Is it possible to change this behavior?

Enabling the spell checker by default would help in eliminating some of the spelling errors that a lot of titles show.

I'm using Firefox.

Comment: Já tinha pensado nisso.

Answer (score 6):

**Isso é um adicional** para a pergunta e não uma resposta.

No Opera e no Chrome os campos `<input>` vem com isto habilitado por padrão, vejam o Opera:

> [image: opera]

Veja no Chrome:

[image: chrome]

Este comportamento **provavelmente só ocorre no Firefox**, vejam este exemplo:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("padrao").spellcheck);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="padrao" value="kpaokd apkdfakod apdkfpasdf"><hr>
<input type="text" value="kpaokd apkdfakod apdkfpasdf" spellcheck="true"><br>
```

Após testar no Firefox tive este resultado:

> [image: firefox]

Note também que no Firefox o `console.log` retornou `false` enquanto no Opera/Chrome retornaram `true`

Comment: De facto eu uso o Firefox.

Comment: @ramaral sim, é apenas um adendo *"técnico"* para os desenvolvedores da SO lerem. Pois desenvolvendo para Web as vezes podem acabar por usar Chrome ou Safari e não perceberem que isto é um comportamento de um browser especifico.